# Проблема с добавлением user при авторизации node js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

[image: Код с ошибкой]

Ссылка на github: https://github.com/AndreyBegma/crm-npm.git
Вот сама ошибка:ReferenceError: model is not defined

Comment: `module` вместо model

Comment: и `const usersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({` вместо `const usersSchema = new mongoose({`